# What is the default memory allocated for a pod

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am setting up a pod say *test-pod* on my google kubernetes engine. When I deploy the pod and see in workloads using google console, I am able to see `100m CPU` getting allocated to my pod by default, but I am not able to see how much memory my pod has consumed. The memory requested section always shows `0` there. I know we can restrict memory limits and initial allocation in the deployment YAML. But I want to know how much default memory a pod gets allocated when no values are specified through YAML and what is the maximum limit it can avail?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have no resource requests on your pod, it can be scheduled anywhere at all, even the busiest node in your cluster, as though you requested 0 memory and 0 CPU.  If you have no resource limits and can consume all available memory and CPU on its node.

(If it’s not obvious, realistic resource requests and limits are a best practice!)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
So does it mean a pod having memory leaks or consuming huge resources can crash other pods and eventually the node if no limits are defined?

Comment: Yup!  Setting correct resource requests is a little bit of an art: set them too low and nodes can get overcommitted, and hit trouble at peak load; too high and nodes will sit idle.  Step 1 is generally to profile containers’ actual memory use.

Comment: Yeah, we have 4 pods on a kubernetes cluster, 3 of them being heavily underutilized (sitting around 10%), and kubernetes insists on ALWAYS scheduling pods to the node using 99% of CPU. Less of an art, more like a dark mistery.

Answer (score 4):

1. You can set limits on individual pods
2. If not , you can set limits on the overall namespace
3. Defaults , no limits

But there are some ticks:

Here is a very nice view of this:

https://blog.balthazar-rouberol.com/allocating-unbounded-resources-to-a-kubernetes-pod

> When deploying a pod in a Kubernetes cluster, you normally have 2
> choices when it comes to resources allotment:
>
> defining CPU/memory resource requests and limits at the pod level
>
> defining default CPU/memory requests and limits at the namespace level
> using a LimitRange

From Docker documentation ( assuming u are using docker runtime ):

> By default, a container has no resource constraints and can use as
> much of a given resource as the host’s kernel scheduler will allow

https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/admin/resource_constraints/

Answer (score 3):

Kubernetes pods' CPU and memory usage can be seen using the [metrics-server](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server) service and the `kubectl top pod` command:

```
$ kubectl top --help
...
Available Commands:
...
  pod         Display Resource (CPU/Memory/Storage) usage of pods
...
```

Example in Minikube below:

```
minikube addons enable metrics-server

# wait 5 minutes for metrics-server to be up and running

$ kubectl top pod -n=kube-system
NAME                               CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)   
coredns-fb8b8dccf-6t5k8            6m           10Mi            
coredns-fb8b8dccf-sjkvc            5m           10Mi            
etcd-minikube                      37m          60Mi            
kube-addon-manager-minikube        17m          20Mi            
kube-apiserver-minikube            55m          201Mi           
kube-controller-manager-minikube   30m          46Mi            
kube-proxy-bsddk                   1m           11Mi            
kube-scheduler-minikube            2m           12Mi            
metrics-server-77fddcc57b-x2jx6    1m           12Mi            
storage-provisioner                0m           15Mi            
tiller-deploy-66b7dd976-d8hbk      0m           13Mi
```

[This link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-cpu-resource/) has more information.

Answer (score 2):

Kubernetes doesn’t provide default resource limits out-of-the-box. This means that unless you explicitly define limits, your containers can consume unlimited CPU and memory.

More details here: https://medium.com/@reuvenharrison/kubernetes-resource-limits-defaults-and-limitranges-f1eed8655474

Answer (score 1):

The real problem in many of these cases is not that the nodes are too small, but that we have not accurately specified resource limits for the pods.

Resource limits are set on a per-container basis using the resources property of a containerSpec, which is a v1 api object of type ResourceRequirements. Each object specifies both “**limits**” and “**requests**” for the types of resources.

If you do not specify a memory limit for a container, one of the following situations applies:

The container has no upper bound on the amount of memory it uses. The container could use all of the memory available on the Node where it is running which in turn could invoke the OOM Killer. Further, in case of an OOM Kill, a container with no resource limits will have a greater chance of being killed.

The container is running in a namespace that has a default memory limit, and the container is automatically assigned the default limit. Cluster administrators can use a **LimitRange** to specify a default value for the memory limit.

When you set a limit, but not a request, kubernetes defaults the request to the limit. If you think about it from the scheduler’s perspective it makes sense.

It is important to set correct resource requests, setting them too low makes that nodes can get overloaded; too high makes that nodes will stuck idle.

Useful article: [memory-limits](https://medium.com/@betz.mark/understanding-resource-limits-in-kubernetes-memory-6b41e9a955f9).

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes doesn’t provide default resource limits out-of-the-box. This means that unless you explicitly define limits, your containers can consume unlimited CPU and memory.

https://medium.com/@reuvenharrison/kubernetes-resource-limits-defaults-and-limitranges-f1eed8655474